# Plotting bar chart matplotlib.pyplot python

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have these very close values to plot using bar chart:

```
[0.786418528, 0.836312033, 0.796715391, 0.834506989, 0.834181085, 0.792882691, 0.787157068]
```

But they appear to be very closed projected on y axis.
[image]

How to make them look more discriminated likes this one from excel?
[image]

Comment: Please add some code that you have tried

Comment: You could change the limits, e.g. with `plt.ylim( min(data)-0.05, max(data)+0.05)`

Comment: Hi JohanC, it works like a charm 

Answer (score 0):

If you know from before the rough range of your data, you can just set the ylim:

```py
plt.ylim([y_min, y_max])
```

A smart way of doing this would be to automatically infer the boundaries of your data from the vector you have (assuming it's called y):

```py
y_min = min(y)
y_max = max(y)
offset = (y_max-y_min)*0.3 # To give us some leeway
plt.ylim([y_min-offset, y_max+offset])
```

Comment: Hi ffdoctor, this works but need a few more lines of code. Anyway the offset is cool though. 